# Prevent resurrection of dead subkernels

Tags: parallelization

How do I prevent Mathematica from trying to resurrect subkernels that it has deemed to be dead? I would like to avoid this:

```
Kernels::rdead:
   Subkernel connected through KernelObject[3, *compute node*] appears dead. 

Parallel`Developer`QueueRun::req:
   Requeueing evaluations {6} assigned to
    KernelObject[3, *compute node*, <defunct>].

LaunchKernels::clone:
   Kernel KernelObject[3, *compute node*, <defunct>] resurrected as
    KernelObject[9, *compute node*].
```

I would prefer it if Mathematica aborts the entire computation if a subkernel dies, or continues on with the remaining subkernels. If a subkernel dies it's most likely because it ran out of memory, so there is little sense in relaunching it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I of course did not think of checking the preferences panel. Under the Parallel tab one can set the desired behaviour for failed evaluations and dead kernels.

These can also be accessed programmatically via

```
SystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "RelaunchFailedKernels"]
SystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "RecoveryMode"]
```

where `"RelaunchFailedKernels"` takes the values `True` or `False`, while `"RecoveryMode"` has values `"Retry"` or `"Abandon"` assigned to it.

I also found a bit more detail in [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ParallelTools/tutorial/FailureRecoveryTracingAndDebugging.html) documentation for the *Parallel Computing Toolkit*, which was eventually merged with Mathematica.